# Form input padding on chrome not displaying

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The styling for my form's input is as follows:

```
.input{


margin: 15px;
padding-inline-start: 2.75%;
border: 0.5px solid rgba(123, 126, 126, 0.41);
border-radius: 10px;
height: 35px;
width: 75%;
```

}

`padding-inline-start: 2.75%;` is meant to add padding to whatever text the user inputs into a field, so the text isn't hitting the edge of the field's border. This works on firefox, but not on chrome and i can't figure out why. thanks

in this screenshot , the text is somewhat indented as you can see. thats what im trying to achieve on chrome and firefox
[image]

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. A single CSS rule isn't sufficient to help you.

Comment: Mozilla suggests that Chrome requires `-webkit-padding-start`, though given the poor browser support you might want to try a different method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
padding-left: 10px;
```